# Extract from image the fixed-height horizontal stripe containing the more information

Tags: python, image-processing, imagemagick

I want to create title banners from various images to illustrate blog posts

Currently i do :

```
# Use IM based script http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/aspectcrop/index.php 
subprocess.call('aspectcrop.sh -a 7:2 %s %s' % (out_image, out_image), shell=True)
```

... which extracts the centered horizontal stripe with ratio 7:2
Works for most images, **but sometimes the image subject is not centered**.

How can I detect which horizontal strip is the most *focused* (something like calculating a FFT criteria for different possible stripes).

- an improvement to current technique would be to be able to give a value (`center (c), north (n), south (s)`) to aspectcrop.sh `gravity` option.
  I could generate the 3 stripes and keep the biggest (~ the one with more details?) image. But it's not elegant and choosing between 3 stripes seems too limiting.
- *brownie* point if the solution does not involve additional dependency like PIL. Ideally, relying on IM subprocess calls would fit me best.

**Update:**
Consider https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1026715/screenshots/eggs.jpg
How to extract automatically 
[image]

rather than (current implementation):

[image]

Comment: How about showing us an example or two of what you are talking about? If you want someone to do something for you, make it easy for them ;-)

Comment: @Mark good idea, done

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the greatest answer, but some thoughts and techniques...

If you do this, you can split the image into a tileset of 20 equal horizontal stripes:

```
convert eggs.jpg -crop x20@ miff:- | montage -tile 1x -geometry +0+5 - montage.jpg
```

[image]

Then, you can calculate some statistics for each tile in the set, and see which ones have a high entropy, for example, as this will likely be things that are sharply focussed, or slices that have a high variance - which means there is lots of detail/colour variation. Then you could choose a few based on the values.... maybe you can come up with other statistics.

```
convert eggs.jpg -crop x20@ -format "%s:%[entropy]:%[standard_deviation]\n" info:

0:0.879802:11026.6
1:0.899478:9334.69
2:0.932645:8009.17
3:0.931683:8206.57
4:0.916827:7005.17
5:0.950524:11547.2
6:0.926702:9338.89
7:0.896852:13487
8:0.950969:20682.1
9:0.938144:20332.6
10:0.922911:13527.2
11:0.932364:15022.7
12:0.915607:12373.9
13:0.921873:12796
14:0.922808:11978.2
15:0.962032:14310.3  <--- high-ish entropy and variance
16:0.952019:15031.2  <--- high-ish entropy and variance
17:0.974847:15504.4  <--- high-ish entropy and variance
18:0.952463:14456.9  <--- high-ish entropy and variance
19:0.927006:13945.5
```

Note that the `%s` in the `-format` statement above refers to the *"scene number"*.